# Rails fields_for not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, fields-for

I am stuck.
I have the following models: profile, user, job.

user has one profile, profile has many jobs.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :jobs

  attr_accessible :user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :headline,:jobs_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :profile
  attr_accessible :username,:email, :password,:profile_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :country

  attr_accessible :company, :country_id, :end_date, :job_title, :profile_id, :start_date
end
```

Now, I want for the user to be able to edit his profile and add a job to his profile. To do this I have used this code:

```
<%= f.fields_for :jobs do |j| %>
          <%= j.label :job_title, "Job Title" %>
          <%= j.text_field :job_title %>

          <%= j.label :company, "Company" %>
          <%= j.text_field :company %>
          ............................
<% end %>
```

But the thing is, this only shows me the fields if the user already has a job to his profile, and I am able to update that. But in this case the array is empty and there will be no iteration. What could I use instead of this, to be sure the forms appear even if the user has no job?

I tried to add a "begin - end while" but it didn't work. Neither checking if the :jobs array is empty and creating a new Job object didn't work...or at least my tries.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

The new method in the controller.

```
def new

  resource = build_resource({})
  profile = resource.build_profile
  profile.jobs += [profile.jobs.build]  
  respond_with resource  

end`
```

Answer (score 7):

If you'd like to include fields for a brand new `Job`, add it to the `jobs` array while you're in the controller:

```
profile.jobs.build
```

In the same way that we often build a dummy record in our `new` actions to pass to `form_for`, we gotta build a dummy record for `fields_for`, too.

Comment: I have edited the post adding the new method in the controller. Still not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true

TO

accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, :update_only => true